# How to get Bootstrap Datepicker calendar to anchor below textbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am having trouble getting the Bootstrap Datepicker calendar to anchor/popup below the entry textbox. Any advice?

Here is my markup, etc.:

```html
<head>
...
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap: Datepicker Plugin -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
</head>
<body>
...
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tour_date">Service Date</label>
<div class="input-group date col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="tour_time">Service Time</label>
  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker col-md-2">
    <input id="timepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-small" data-minute-step="30">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap: Bootstrap Datepicker Plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#tickets .input-group.date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        datesDisabled: ['01/01/1970', '12/31/2099']
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

**Screen Shot - My Behavior**
[image]

**Screen Shot - Desired Behavior**
[image]

**Amended with added styling issues:**
[image]

Comment: can you reproduce the behavior? works fine here -> http://jsfiddle.net/cy0kx44o/147/

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad. Every time I "reproduce" the behavior I get what you see in the screen shot. That's why I posted the QA.

Comment: Here's an observation I have after in-depth study @davidkonrad. My input label to floats left of the input box. The sample generator at bootstrap datepicker does not take a label into consideration. Your fiddle has the label positioned above the input box. I think the label is the problem somehow and I don't think the datepicker plugin considers labels.

Comment: plus the plugin does not consider the bootstrap column alignment (see my amended screen shot). This plugin is probably fine until you wrap it in the Bootstrap `<div class="form-group">` container.

Comment: Can you try editing the js file and changing ```appendOffset``` to be ```container.position()``` instead of ```container.offset()```. That fixed it for me - I'm going to open an issue, but not sure if it's the correct solution.

Comment: Added a comment instead to https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1662

Comment: Cool, thank you @AndyBeverley. I will try it over the weekend.

Comment: No worries @H.Ferrence - I actually found it only worked under some circumstances, but give it a go anyway. Might be worth sharing your experiences on that Github issue.

Comment: Just in case you didn't see my comment on the Github issue, removing ```appendOffset``` altogether seems to fix the alignment in all the circumstances I've tried.

Comment: Thanks @AndyBeverley for your great assistance here. I am using the CouldFare CDN version and it looks like it is still running at ver1.5.0. Is there another work around until the problem gets fixed at the CDN without having to install the plugin on my server?

Comment: Well I downloaded `bootstrap-datepicker.js` and removed line 706 `appendOffset = container.offset()`. That causes the popup calendar to not appear.

Comment: I also tried changing it to `appendOffset = container.position()` and that did not do the trick on my server.

Comment: The actual answer (_for me_) is this: change line 718 to `top = offset.top - 0;`

Comment: @H.Ferrence - when I say remove ```appendOffset```, I mean remove that logic of the code (which is probably what you've achieved by your last comment). Removing just that one line probably results in a javascript exception ;-)

Comment: In terms of using a CDN, that won't be possible unless you find one with the issue fixed, so you'll have to use your own local copy for the time being. Might be worth going back to the original Github issue and adding your comments.

Comment: Thanks @AndyBeverley. I downloaded my own copy of the .js and changed line 718 to `top = offset.top - 0;`. That solved it for me.

Comment: Here's a bizarre discovery: when you use the CDN version (`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js`) the back and forward arrows **work properly** when navigating the calendar widget month-to-month. However, when you download the seemingly same version of the script from GitHub (`bootstrap-datepicker.js` v1.5.0) the back and forward arrows **do not work properly** when navigating the calendar widget month-to-month. Crazy...